# Android crashing when operning

Tags: java, android

I have been creating an application to log and register users, in used a asynctask but think i have done it incorrelty. please see below for error messages and code

```
04-16 11:27:17.160: D/AndroidRuntime(31658): Shutting down VM
04-16 11:27:17.160: W/dalvikvm(31658): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c4c700)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.applicationnfclogin/com.applicationnfclogin.DashboardActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #92: Error inflating class progressbar
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #92: Error inflating class progressbar
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at com.applicationnfclogin.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:23)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    ... 11 more
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.progressbar" on path: /data/app/com.applicationnfclogin-1.apk
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
04-16 11:27:17.175: E/AndroidRuntime(31658):    ... 21 more
04-16 11:27:37.400: D/AndroidRuntime(32009): Shutting down VM
04-16 11:27:37.400: W/dalvikvm(32009): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c4c700)
```

(I know its a mine field)
please see below for login page code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.applicationnfclogin.R;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.applicationnfclogin.internal.DatabaseHandler;
import com.applicationnfclogin.internal.JSONParser;
import com.applicationnfclogin.internal.NFCHandler;

import com.applicationnfclogin.internal.UserFunctions;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

private 

//NfcAdapter Nfc;
Button btnLogin;
Button btnNfcScan;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private ProgressBar progress;
private ProgressBar progress2;
private TextView text; 
// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "Firstname";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "Lasrname";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "Username";
private static String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at "; 


@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progress2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //Nfc = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(null);

    //Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Username = inputUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                        final int value = i;
                        checklogin();
                        progress.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                text.setText("Loading");
                                progress.setProgress(value);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
            LoggingTask task = new LoggingTask();
            task.execute(Username, password);
        }
        private void checklogin() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        /*
         * User logged in task
         */
        class LoggingTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
                UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = userFunctions.loginUser(KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD);

                try{ 
                if (!KEY_USERNAME.equals(KEY_USERNAME)   &&!KEY_PASSWORD.equals(KEY_PASSWORD)) {
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                            if(Integer.parseInt(res) ==1) {
                                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                                JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                                db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME), json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME), json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME), json_user.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                                Intent dashboard = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(dashboard);
                            }else{ loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect Username and or Password");
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                        return null;
                    }
            }

            });                         


    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                        final int value = i;
                        Register();
                        progress.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                text.setText("loading");
                                progress.setProgress(value);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();

        }
        private void Register() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        { 
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();


        }
    });



}

}
```

The main page (dashboard):

```
 package com.applicationnfclogin;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import com.applicationnfclogin.R;
import com.applicationnfclogin.internal.NFCHandler;
import com.applicationnfclogin.internal.UserFunctions;

public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
UserFunctions userFunctions;
Button btnLogout;
Button btnNfcScan;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    btnNfcScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNfcScan);



    /**Dashboard Screen for the application * */       
    // Check login status in database
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions ();
    CheckLoginTask task = new CheckLoginTask();
    task.execute();

}


/*
 * CHeck user logged in task
 */
private class CheckLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void...nothing) {
        return userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(DashboardActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result){
            // user already logged in show databoard
            //setContentView (R.layout.activity_dashboard);
            btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

            btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View argo) {
                    userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    Intent login = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);

                    startActivity(login);
                    finish();
                }



            });
        }else{
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
        }

    // Scan
    //this button is null and throws the exception
     //the async task worked fine
    btnNfcScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View argo){
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    NFCHandler.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();

        }
    });
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a ProgressBar wrong in your xml (android.view.progressbar), instead of (for instance)

```
 <ProgressBar
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html